# Are Android generated ID really immutable?

Tags: java, android

I have defined an Activity in an Android app containing 9 button. Each button have to listen to the same event listener.

Looking at generated R class, their Ids are defined :

```
 public static final int btn1=0x7f040001;
 ...
 public static final int btn1=0x7f040009;
```

My question is: it is ok to add the listeners cycling the ID in a for loop?

```
for (int i= R.id.btn1; i<=R.id.btn9;i++)
{
   Button button = (Button)findViewById(i);
   button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             ...
        }
   });
}
```

Or there in some situation in which Id get reassigned by the compiler, breaking my code?

I'm using Intellij Idea environment to build the app.

Comment: No, do not do this. You have no control over how Buttons (or any other XML resource) are assigned integer IDs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fear this would be a very bad idea in the event your R file is regenerated with non-consecutive IDs.. your better option would be to store an int array containing your IDs and loop through that

ex.

```
int[] views = new int[] { R.id.btn1, R.id.btn2, R.id.btn3, ...... R.id.btn9 };

for (int i= 0; i< views.length ;i++)
{
   Button button = (Button)findViewById(views[i]);
   button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             ...
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: At that point, you can just do `for (int i : views) ...`. No need to muck around with `views.length` and `i++`. In your loop as you have it now, you want to write `findViewById(views[i])`, not just `i`.

Comment: Updated to fix the findViewById. Thanks :)